# how to save textbox data in database using javascript json

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnaddrecords]").bind("click", function () {
            var user = {};
            user.invoice_no = $("[id*=txtinvoice]").val();
            user.sale_description = $("[id*=txtsale]").val();
            user.transdate = $("[id*=txttdate]").val();
            user.transtype = $("[id*=ddtransaction]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SaveUser",
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("User has been added successfully.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });


            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a question

Comment: Why are you using Ajax if you're going to load a new page afterwards anyway?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems in the code you shared:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

    $(function () {
```

A script element can load one script. It can load it from a URL using a `src` attribute, or it can be embedded a child node. You can't have both at the same time.

You need two script elements.

You should also consider using the current version of jQuery. 1.6.2 is very old.

---

You say you are sending JSON:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

but:

```
'{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}'
```

Will not give you JSON.

You need:

```
JSON.stringify({ user: user })
```

This assumes that `Default.aspx/SaveUser` expects a JSON formatted request in the first place.